# Cannot delete file with special caracters under LINUX

Tags: delete-file

When trying to run a PHP script under Linux, my command fails and I inherited a a new file in the folder.

The file is called ");?            ?for ($j=0;$j".

Impossible to delete with rm, impossible to move...[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYp5S.png)

Any idea, please ?

Comment: The way I would go is type `rm \"`then type tab.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate ? Not sure I get the exact command...

Comment: The idea is that your file starts with the " character, so i suggested you typing the start of the command, then using the tab key for bash completion. Otherwise you can search for which characters you shourd escape.

Comment: Magnificent !! The idea of escaping the 1st caracter is briliant. Actually it was a "(" and escaping it worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just an untested idea :

Maybe you can try to delete all the repository, with `rm -R folder_name`.
You could also add -f : `rm -R -f folder_name`

Of course, don't forget to save the other files beforehand, but it should be easy as there are just a few.

Comment: That (unfortunately) does not work. CentOS prevents the deleting of the folder because of the file...